# Cross platform ajax post request for rails

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can not find proper code for ajax post request using jquery. Can anyone help me. Code that i have used before is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit-button').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:3000/batches.json",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                data: {     
                    batch: {
                      name: $("#name").val(),
                      course_id: $("#course_id").val(),
                      start_date: $("#start_date").val(),
                      end_date: $("#end_date").val(),
                      batch_status: $("#batch_status").val(),
                      }
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                     console.log(data);
                     return false;
                },
            })
        });
    })
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The problem is that when i remove xhrFields parameter it works properly and displays all the errors in correct format but when i save my date there is unauthorized access to the backend (rails). But when i don't delete it data get saved and status in rails log is 200 but in browser console log it is different

Comment: why is that so... is there any problem in my jquery...